# Numbering of Halachot in Mishneh Thora

Tags: rambam, mishneh-torah

Shalom

I am a Noahide studying publications concerning the Noahide covenant.

I have noticed that references to the Mishneh Torah by the Rambam always come with two different numbers for the Halacha, like in

*Book of Judgments, Laws of Claimant and Respondant 15:4[2]*

(The above is supposed to be a Halacha that the Rambam codified using a 500 year old retired Talmud manuscript made of animal skin that he discovered in his time, thereby identifying and rectifying a corrupt tradition that was added into the Babylonian Talmud)

What is the difference between the numbers, and, if I am looking for this Halacha in the English Moznaim, which one is it,2 or 4?

Thanks !

Comment: It might help if you tell us precisely where you've come across these references. Or even better, a link

Comment: Bar-Ron, Rabbi Michael Shelomo - Guide for the Noahide - Lightcatcher Books 2010 (2nd Ed) - Preface, p.iv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the first reference (i.e. 15:4) is following the numbering system used in Yemenite copies of Mishneh Torah (e.g. that used by [Mechon Mamre](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/d315.htm)).

The reference in parentheses (so 15:2 in your case) is the conventional system used in most printed copies. And I believe that Moznaim's English edition follows this too.

In any event, I think you may have been having problems here because the reference is incorrect. You don't want Laws of Claimant and Respondant, but rather Laws of Lender and Borrower (*hilkhot malveh ve-loveh*).

[This](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1159454/jewish/Malveh-veLoveh-Chapter-15.htm) seems to be the language of Rambam that you're describing:

> This is a scribal error. For this reason, the halachic authorities erred because of those texts. I have researched ancient versions of the text and I found that they state that the borrower's word is accepted. In Egypt, a portion of an ancient text of the Talmud written on parchment, as was the custom in the era approximately 500 years before the present era, came to my possession. I found two versions of this law among those parchments.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you ! The Rabbi is indeed of Yemenite MinHag (while seemingly American-born).

Comment: Did the Rambam ever number subchapter units? I know he marked them as paragraphs, but seemingly all these numbering systems aren't really his.