# Why do Rambam references use a weird convention?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam

For example, in the Ein Mishpat when quoting the Tur/Shulchan Aruch, he says ”<sefer>-<siman>-<se'if>". With the Rambam, though, it's "<perek> from <sefer>, <halachah>". The first is more intuitive because it starts with the most broad and goes to the most specific. But if you don't even like that question, then let the question just be - why is there a difference altogether? I've seen those conventions carry consistently across other sefarim as well, although I can't quote anything off the top of my head.

Comment: Perhaps https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133770/numbering-of-halachot-in-mishneh-thora#comment444802_133774

Comment: @DoubleAA It doesn't really answer the question - regardless of who _created_ the subchapter units in the Rambam, the semantic difference in reference remains.

Comment: If one of the counts is not original, then it makes sense it is written last.

Comment: @DoubleAA On what basis would you say that? It might make intuitive sense to you, but it doesn't to me. Do you have a source that supports that?