Is it Mishna Vrura?
According to the rules of dikduk, is the correct pronunciation of משנה ברורה "Mishna V'rura", without the dagesh in the beis? If so, I'm curious as to why most people pronounce it with a dagesh.

Most people mispronounce the whole trifecta: Mishna Berura, Biur Halacha, and Shar Hatzion.

Should the Rambam’s work be called Mishneh Sorah?

@J.W. no https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/133770/759

Yes, in a strictly grammatical sense it should be pronounced mishnah v’rurah. However, the pronunciation of Hebrew phrases, especially everyday terms, is largely cultural (and practical). Hence, most people will pronounce it as Mishnah B’rurah, Divrei Torah, Tosfos etc. (as opposed to Divrei Sorah and Tosafos.)

So grammatically it’s also vereishis vara elokim?

@RebHarvey no. As a rule of thumb, if you have two words in the same phrase and the first ends on a vowel sound (not a consonant) and the second word starts with a letter that can be dagesh or not, the second word loses the dagesh. So "Mishna Verurah", but "Nodaɣ Bihudah." (ɣ as the vellar fricative, 'ayin; it's a consonant.) As a teacher of mine said, if it's "Rabbi Moshe Feinstein", his son should be "Rabbi Dovid Pinestein" instead.

Also worth noting that many of these pronunciations are filtered through Yiddish, where בדגכפת fricatization isn't productive.

@magicker72 agreed; in my humble opinion, centuries of forcing Hebrew through a Germanic lens did not do the poor Semitic language any favors.

@Shalom [re. Comment #1] No instance of ע has been a velar fricative for the past few millennia. That variant merged with the epiglottal fricative [ʕ] around the end of the Biblical era.

@Qwertrl fascinating, thanks! The point is that Hebrew grammar remembers it's still a consonant, even if most Ashkenazim do not.
